# Fish Oil smell in closet - electrical failure/hazard?

Tags: electrical, smell

I recently moved into a rental house. There is an obvious fish oil smell in the closet of the room above the garage. And by fish oil smell, I mean if you literally took a fish oil supplement and popped it open, it would smell like the closet. I removed stuff from the closet to rule them out as sources. I also put some shallow tubs of baking soda in there, but the smell is pretty strong. I also didn't notice the smell before.

I'm worried that it may be an electrical issue, but I have my doubts:

1. The smell *only* comes from the closet. It's maybe 3ft x 4ft. If I stand outside the closet door I can smell it, but not if I go to the adjoining wall or the opposite wall. I also don't smell it in the garage underneath the closet. I can't get close to the closet in the attic since the roofs are at two different levels. The only thing over the closet should be ducting for the AC.
2. The electrical outlet next to the closet is unused. There is no outlet in the closet, nor is there a light fixture.
3. The wall switch for the room's ceiling fan is on the adjoining wall to the closet, but I do not smell anything from  around there. The smell doesn't go away or get worse depending on if the switches are turned on or off. There is a small light that illuminates the switches when they are turned off.

Any thoughts on if this sounds like it's probably/definitely an electrical issue?

Comment: What is "fish oil"? It can't be a common thing, since I've never heard of it. I vaguely remember being dosed with cod liver oil as a child, but I don't think that has much of an odor. And what makes you associate it with an "electrical issue"? I've smelt plenty of electrical catastrophes, but none of them smelt remotely "fishy".

Comment: Is the closet carpeted?  If so there probably was something spilled on it at one time, or animal/s soiled it.

Comment: @kreemoweet  There is information/warnings on the internet that say if you have a fish smell from an outlet, it should be checked/breaker turned off.  Something about heated plastic smelling like fish.  Not sure how true it is.

Comment: @kreemoweet ever heard of cod liver oil?

Comment: Interesting - never heard of a short or burning plastic having a fish smell. Since this is a rental, you'll have to get the landlord/maintenance staff in to look at it. In the US, at least, electrical work _must_ be done by a licensed electrician.

Comment: I've never associated electrical trouble with fish oil.  Could it simply be a fish oil spill?

Comment: Scent can be a weird thing, and can be quite individual.

Answer (score 1):

I have never smelt fish smells from an outlet.  Sometimes fresh concrete can smell like that.

What I have seen a number of times is that a single ant dies across a switch.  It releases formic acid which attracts other ants.  I have had it twice that the switch stops working because of the bulk of dead ants.  Formic acid is strong.  Maybe it smells like fish to you.

> Ants are known to have the distinctive odour of formic acid, but only some people can smell it. Most people say it smells quite lemony or citronella-like, while one species smells like blue cheese.

From [Smelling ants:](https://www.newshub.co.nz/home/health/2017/12/things-you-thought-were-normal-but-are-actually-genetic-quirks.html)

I found this (and more posts like this), so get it checked out.

> **What Causes the Fishy Smell?**
> When a circuit overheats, the plastics and heat-resistant chemicals used in outlets, circuit breakers, or wiring insulation may emit a fishy or urine-like smell. The odor can be carried throughout the house by the HVAC system, and it may intensify or fade with changing temperatures and circuit usage. This can make it difficult to identify which room the smell is coming from, or which outlet.
>
> The odor can be caused by any number of electrical problems, including:
>
> - Overloaded circuits
> - Undersized wiring
> - Undersized circuit breakers
> - Loose plugs in outlets
> - Damaged outlets that are arcing or sparking
> - Frayed or damaged electrical insulation
> - Short circuits
>
> Usually, the fish smell is an early indicator of a serious electrical problem that could lead to a fire. That is why it is important to have your electrical system professionally inspected when you notice a fishy, urine-like, or burnt plastic smell near any outlets or electrical devices.

From [Why Does My Outlet Smell Like Fish?](https://gacservices.com/blog/outlet-smell-like-fish/)

Comment: Undersized circuit breakers is an interesting one.  I would expect it to trip, than to smell.

Comment: Never having smelled it myself, I am dubious of the whole thing, but its out there.  Maybe I should burn some TPS tomorrow and see.  :-)  And I would have expected arcing to smell like ozone.